# Sql date field is not getting saved exactly

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, insert

I am trying to insert a date value **'2010-03-14 02:00:00 AM'**(Day light saving start time for 2010 year) in a datetime field of a table in sql server 2005. The date is saved as    **'2010-03-14 03:00:00 AM'** The server is installed in US(EST time zone).

Can anyone tell me the reason why the date is saving differently?

Thanks
Rupa

Comment: No I can't, but it'll probably make your life easier further down the line if you store times in UTC.

Answer (score 2):

As the clock jumps from 0200 to 0300 one of these times does not exist.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) says

> A digital display of local time does not read 02:00 exactly at the shift, but instead jumps from 01:59:59.9 either forward to 03:00:00.0 or backward to 01:00:00.0.

In my view you should save all times in a database in GMT/UTC and only use the local time zone on display in the client - thus in the database all times will be monotonically increasing (that is the times will not jump back at the end of daylight saving)

Comment: I am inserting records in DB in GMT format only.What my actual problem is I have first date(2009-10-25 08:00:00 AM) and last date(2009-11-07 09:00:00 AM).When these dates are saved in DB in GMT as firstdate(2009-10-25 12:00:00 PM) and lastdate(2009-11-07 02:00:00 PM). The time difference for firstdate and lastdate (in front end) is one hour and difference after saving in db is 2 hours. If i want to do any manipulation in db means, it giving odd results because of difference change for front end and DB.Any idea to sort out this issue?

Comment: I am confused. If yiou are entering "'2010-03-14 02:00:00 AM'(Day light saving start time for 2010 year) " that is not GMT as GMT does not have a daylight saving. (Also if using British times note that the time of change is 0100 not 0200)

I would get the database set to GMT not EST. If not you will have to convert the input time from GMT to EST

Answer (score 2):

GMT != UTC.  GMT has Daylight Savings, UTC does not.
Save your dates as UTC and you're good to go.

Comment: That is incorrect.  GMT is pretty much synonymous with UTC.  UTC is internationally standardised, GMT is not.  GMT does NOT change in the summer for daylight savings time; the UK moves onto BST (British Summer Time) which is GMT+1.

Answer (score 1):

one point: GMT by definition does not change throughout the year: in Britain one exists either on GMT or on BST (British Summer Time).

That aside, I would recheck your time zone settings for your db and your server.